# Darken picture on hover and other css details

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Hello people from StackOverflow.
I'm trying to do something exactly like in this website: http://anayafilms.com/ (work section).
It's basically an image but on mouse over, it gets darken, a text at the bottom and two "buttons" (just some font awesome icons in a circle), along with some basic animation.
So far I only have the image in a div and no idea on how to do that, so if anyone can help me out that'd be amazing.

[Before and after, just to illustrate it in case you don't wanna go on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Xa2.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you really need it to do, you might be able to do this without javascript. Here is an example that makes use of the css pseudo class `:hover` and some absolute positioning. I'm darkening the background, which you can set as an image, by using a layer above it with a `opacity: .5` black background created using `background: rgba(0,0,0,.5)`.

```css
.css-rollover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.css-rollover:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;

}

.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.overlay p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX( -50% );
}

.overlay .fa-links {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.overlay .fa-links a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height:20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="css-rollover">
  <div class="bg" ></div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="fa-links">
      <a href="#">A</a>
      <a href="#">B</a>
    </div>
    <p>You're hovering...</p></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for you help. My biggest problem here is on how do I position the items like in the pic attached to my post, i mean with the two font awesome icons in a circle in the middle of the overlay and another text in the bottom. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Sure Luc, I updated the snippet. The overlay here is already using absolute positioning so you just apply some absolute positioning to the child elements you want to include. Centering with absolutely positioned elements is easily accomplished using `top`, `left`, `bottom`, or `right`. The trickiest part is centering, but you can use 50% to center relative to the parent, and then use transforms to adjust the child position using a percentage of it's own size, as in `transform: translateX( -50% );`

Comment: Your sample site also zooms the bg image on hover. That can also be done in css but you should get this base style working for you and than add that in. I'd post a separate question if you can't get it going but you can link it here if you are using this code to start and want some help with the background scaling.

Comment: Hello JasonB, thank you so much for your help, that's pretty much what I was looking for, I do have a last question tho, before, I was using an img instead of background url, because I wanna use img-responsive class from bootstrap to make it responsive. Is that still possible though?

Comment: Before checking your answer I had this done: https://jsfiddle.net/lucasf10/bm661n7q/5/

Comment: Yeah, I think that the wrapper div should take on the size of the img and the img uses the bootstrap css. As long as the overlay is absolutely positioned and the img is not, there won't be additional items messing with the size of that container div. Also, I like the blur effect on the image hover in the fiddle.